# How do I make this a 3d shape in blender?

Tags: modeling

I'm brand new to blender and I'm trying to make this a 3d model in blender 2.8.

I tried to warp a UV sphere and then cut it up but couldn't really get the desired results I wanted.

[image: shape]

Comment: Without a plan view,there's no single 3D object which this corresponds to.

Comment: I would create a Curve and Spin it to create a 3D Mesh then create a UV using Project from View after setting the view to Front Orthographic. Then add the Image Texture. This assumes you do not need the stripes to be geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

I used your provided image to determine X-Z slices of 3-D space that should be transparent, and then spherically displaced a highly subdivided plane to get a 3-D shape that seemed reasonable given the image (although it is not rotationally symmetric about the Z axis, which you might be wanting).

I used two objects in my scene: a Plane at (0, -0.5, 0) and an Empty at (0,0,0) (the Empty was just used to make the Mirror modifier mirror in the intended manner without my having to reset the main object's Origin).

Here's the small modifier stack I used:

[image]

Where the displacement used this quadratic sphere texture, with Color Ramp enabled and tuned to taste (this controls how wide/tall the resulting object is):

[image]

I enforced the transparent stripes with this shader, where the input image is the jpeg you provided:

[image]

(not shown: my collapsed Principled BSDF node's Base Color was set to Black; this is why the non-transparent stripes in the image of the object are black)

I used Eevee as my Renderer, and had Blend Mode: Alpha Clip (in the Materials settings for this material) and Film: Transparent (in Render settings) enabled.

Note that this approach:

1. Doesn't convert the transparent strips to geometry (although you could do something similar to this with a Mask node to achieve a similar effect, and if you were to do so, that would make selecting and deleting those vertices straightforward, which would let you embed this information in the geometry)
2. Yields a very large number of extraneous vertices if you apply the modifier stack to convert it to raw geometry. Here is what the result looks like, after applying the modifier stack in order and viewing the object in Edit Mode, Rendered View:

[image]

You can easily select most of the undesirable vertices outside of the main, central area of the object (in case you'd like to delete them) by using Select Similar: Normal, although this isn't perfect and you'll still need to clean up some of them manually. Depending on your use case, you might also want to re-topologize the final object to simplify its geometry (it is nice in that it contains only/primarily quads, but it also has lots of vertices that occupy exactly or almost exactly the same point in space, and some of its internal vertices could be unnecessary as well, depending on your final use case).

Comment: Wow thanks for this! I'll try to follow along if I can. I'm looking at the finished product you made - is there a way to make the shape more spherical and rounded?

Comment: I think the shape could be made more spherical by truncating the input image a bit (right now only a small portion of the input image is used, which makes the quadratic sphere displacement a little awkward to apply properly), and also by playing with the Color Ramp/interpolation options used in the quadratic sphere texture for that same displacement, as well as tinkering with the displacement strength in the displacement modifier itself. I'll play around with that a bit this evening.

Let me know if you have trouble understanding anything. Happy to clarify where needed.

Comment: @NathanP Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Comment: On revisiting this, I believe my solution is unnecessarily complex; the subdivide+displace modifier isn't needed (I had a sightly different approach in mine when I added them). Almost all of the work in my solution is being done by the shader, and that can be combined with an arbitrary underlying object. See Robin Betts' solution for a good example, or you could use any other object you prefer (a sphere, cube, Suzanne, etc). When I have more time I'll edit my solution to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, just using proportional edit on a cylinder:

(Before subdividing vertically, select two faces, one apart, and then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> add every other vertical face, to assign different materials to all, and then selection, if you want to make stripes)

[image]

(With Z up, <kbd>O</kbd> Proprotional Edit, connected)

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> equator selected,scale it out.

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> 4 single vertices, front and back, top and bottom.

[image]

I don't know, it's just one of many 3D shapes your graphic could have..